# AngularJS: How to animate ng-repeat on load using ng-animate

Tags: angularjs

Folks!

How can I get the divs created using `ng-repeat` to slide down..I mean grow in size ON LOAD.

I want to achieve this using `ng-animate` and the animation should trigger when the page loads.

I am looking at [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat#animations) example given in the docs wherein the animation beautifully runs when you filter the items but not when the page loads.

I am using version 1.2.0

A working fiddle or plunk would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would like the same question answered.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to show ng-repeat animation on page load, the target array has to be initially empty. Then assigned with values.

Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/mRZFFX?p=preview

This demo used `$timeout` to set `friends` value in a later time so the enter animation can be triggered.

Comment: It looks like this method doesn't work in every cases. On this fiddle for example : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/avOff/HQ4vc/4/). It' is maybe due to the ng-if inside the ng-repeat, I don't know...

Comment: @aIMAC The element that is repeating is the `<ul ng-repeat="proj in projects">...</ul>` in your case, not `.test-anim`. So you have to specify animation for `ul` instead of `.test-anim`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you look below url example of nganimate in ng-repeat:

http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move

If you are using latest version of Angularjs you need to inject 'ngAnimate' in your app and also need to added dependent js file that is "angular-animate.min.js"

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to achieve this. AFAIK the only way is to add the items to the list after page digest.

Here is [another example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mRZFFX) courtesy of [Steve Guilford](http://disqus.com/steveguilford/) if it helps.