# Programatically changing ngShow doesn't make use of ngAnimate classes

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

I'm trying to trigger ngShow via my controller, it works, but it doesn't make use of the ngAnimate classes that I need to get a fade transition.

It works like it should if I use a button to toggle ngShow, but not if I toggle it programmatically. Is this expected behavior? Can I get around it?

Plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/swJDP1KBBxcRfK9auYPs?p=preview

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="visible">
    <div ng-show="visible" class="wrap" role="document">
      Hello
    </div>
  </body>
```

```
var app = angular.module( "app", ['ngAnimate']);

app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.visible = false;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $rootScope.visible = true;
});
```

```
.wrap.ng-hide-add-active {
  display: block!important;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out all;
}

.wrap.ng-hide-remove-active {
  display: block!important;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out all;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.wrap.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're run block and controller code likely get executed in the same digest cycle so Angular doesn't see the `visible` variable changing. This would work if you put your controller code in a timeout. e.g.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.visible = true;
  });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5IhGE3ol5kI64OlT1e8v?p=preview

Comment: I noticed it works with timeout aswell. It feels a bit hacky though. No other solutions to this problem?

Comment: Not that I know if. I did a quick search but only came across the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20505571/373655